# grpc authentication using email

Tags: authentication, google-api, grpc

I'm completing a python grpc server function-wise and being ready for deployment. Thusfar I have unsecure communication (pretty much the helloworld example when it comes to security). I thought I could put in place an authentication mechanism for my server in a reasonable amount of time after I observed that there was [some documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) on this very topic provided by google. Closer investigation let me to believe otherwise.

The case is simple: Users (fellow colleagues of mine) login to their company mail (gmail) and use  the resulting token (JWT, OAuth, OAuth2, I don't care) to gain access to the grpc server I wrote. No one else gets in.

Since googling grpc+authentication has been fruitless so far I believe I'm on the wrong track on how I should approach this kind of problem. So therefore the questions:

- Given this use case, should my grpc server have any concern with authentication? If so, are there examples? Or should this be handled by a different system? If so, what system?
- I noticed a lot of articles mentioning Envoy+gRPC. Can Envoy help me out here? Is it designed to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The gRPC authentication can follow the same approach of a normal HTTP, the only thing you need to have in mind is that the authentication check would be placed in an gRPC interceptor and you will be looking at the metadata to get the creadentials. Unfortunately, I don't have an example to do it with Python but you can search in "how to add gRPC Server interceptors in Python" and then "how to work with gRPC metadata in Python"

[Here](https://github.com/apssouza22/grpc-production-go/blob/master/serverinterceptor/security.go) an example in Golang, maybe it can give you the idea